# php - how to get current dir of server but not current filename?

Tags: php, path

SOLUTION

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$feedtitle = str_replace(" ", "", $feedtitle);
$feedtitle = strtolower($feedtitle);
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, "/"));
$feedlink = "http://" . "$path" . "/"  . "$feedtitle" . '.xml';
```

PROBLEM

I am trying to generate a name for an rss feed from another field (feed title). In my query I have :

```
$path = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$feedtitle = str_replace(" ", "", $feedtitle);
$feedtitle = strtolower($feedtitle);
$feedlink = "$path" . "$feedtitle" . '.xml';
```

If feedtitle is **my rss feed**, $feedlink will have the value **myrssfeed.xml** so that part of the code works but I'm having problems with the path. Instead of writing the current path the above writes the current path & the name of the current file! e.g. if the script I'm using for this is named **feedlink.php** the path that is stored in the $feedlink variable is :

```
mywebsite.com/mydir/feedlink.phpmyrssfeed.xml
```

How do I remove the name of the script?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you requested the site as `mywebsite.com/mydir/feedlink.php` you should consider removing everything past the last `/` and then add your filename to that:

```
$path = substr($path, 0, strrpos($path, "/") + 1);
```

Comment: Using that gives : mywebsite.com/mydirmyrssfeed.xml so it's removing the / after the dir.

Answer (score 1):

With the `str_replace()` function

```
 $feedlink = str_replace("feedlink.php", "",  $feedlink);
```

Comment: Used a combination of your code and Kevin's to resolve it. Thanks.